# Searching google.com using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On performing inspect element on google.com input, I get:

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="both" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: none;">
```

Now if I do: `$("#lst-ib")`, I get input object as expected. But if I do: `$("#lst-ib").val("hello world!")`, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function(…)
```

Same thing is happening with Bing.com. Can someone explain why is it happening and how can I search on these website by using `Javascript` or `Jquery`.

Comment: $ doesn't mean is jquery. it can be just a namespace for some selector function writen by their internal programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is google doesn't use jQuery, so you can't use jQuery functions there.

try this

```
//change the input
document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "What you want to find";
//submit form
document.getElementById("tsf").submit();
```

It will change the search input as you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @SKG you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The object that is being retrieved with `$("#lst-ib")` is not your usual jquery object. Google must be using a customized JS library. However, you can change the value of the input by this:

```
$("#lst-ib").value = 'new value';
```

Comment: `$("#lst-ib").value` will not work for sure...

Comment: @Rayon : Tried it, it does :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ozhwvz3L/

Comment: OP says "On performing inspect element on google.com input". Try it in the console on google.com because that's what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`$` dosen't always mean its `jQuery`. It can be used as a shorthand for any library.

If you want to use `$` as `Jquery` only always pass `jQuery` as object and then use.. like

```
 (function ($) { 
   //jQuery Code. 
 })(jQuery);
```